# determinant of metric on complexified vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a complex manifold of dimension $n$ with Hermitian metric $g$. Extend $g$ to $TM^{\mathbb{C}}$ linearly. I believe that at each $p$ we can say a basis for $T_pM$ as a real vector space is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1},\dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_n}$$ and so a basis for $T_qM^{\mathbb{C}}$, as a real vector space, is given by $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1},\dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_n},\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1},\dots, \sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n},\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_n}.$$

Let $$g_{i\overline j}=g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}-\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}+\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right).$$

My question is, what is the relationship between $\det g_{ij}$ and $\det g_{i\overline j}$. Is it that, $$\det(g_{i\overline j})=\frac{1}{2^n}\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}?$$ If this is true, then that would help me out alot! But I am really struggling to prove it or say something remotely similar. Any help would be appreciated.